# Inconsistent Results when Running Python Code in a Separate Thread

Tags: python, multithreading, raspberry-pi, gpio

I have a Python script that interacts with a Raspberry Pi to handle button presses. The script reads values from GPIO pins, converts those values to binary and then hex, and compares the converted value to a pre-set list of button press values.

Here is the `get_binary()` function:

```py
def get_binary():
    num1s = 0  
    binary = 1  
    command = []  
    previousValue = 0  
    value = GPIO.input(pin)  

    while value:
        sleep(0.0001)
        value = GPIO.input(pin)

    startTime = datetime.now()

    while True:
        if previousValue != value:
            now = datetime.now()
            pulseTime = now - startTime
            startTime = now
            command.append((previousValue, pulseTime.microseconds))

        if value:
            num1s += 1
        else:
            num1s = 0

        if num1s > 10000:
            break

        previousValue = value
        value = GPIO.input(pin)

    for (typ, tme) in command:
        if typ == 1:
            if tme > 1000:
                binary = binary *10 +1
            else:
                binary *= 10

    if len(str(binary)) > 34:
        binary = int(str(binary)[:34])

    return binary
```

And here is the `handle_button_press()` function:

```py
def handle_button_press(queue, stop_event):
    while not stop_event.is_set():
        in_data = convert_to_hex(get_binary())
        for i, button in enumerate(BUTTONS):
            if hex(button) == in_data:
                button_name = BUTTON_VARS[i]
                with current_button.get_lock():  
                    current_button.value = button_name
                queue.put(button_name)
```

The script works perfectly when run normally. However, when `handle_button_press()` is run from a separate thread, the `in_data` value changes with each call.

Why does the value of `in_data` change when `handle_button_press()` is run from a separate thread, and how can I get consistent values as when running the script normally?